# "almost surely" convergence of a special sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of **equally distributed** random variables.

Suppose that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\mathbb{E}[X_n]=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n^4]=0$.

**Prove or Disprove**: $X_n\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}\to0$.

I feel that the statement is true and I tried to prove it.

I said that since the random variables are all equally distributed then the random variables $|X_1|,|X_2|,\dots$ are also equally distributed.

So, $\forall n,m\in\mathbb{N}:\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]=\mathbb{E}[|X_m|]$. Let's call this value $S$.

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n^4]=0$, it  must be that $S=0$ (not sure about this).

Therefore, $P[X_n=0]=1$ and $X_n\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}\to0$.

Is it true?

Comment: Are you sure you have your hypothesis right? Does "equally distributed" mean "identically distributed"?

Comment: I have translated it from another language. I think that they mean "equally distributed". Otherwise the sequence is constant, right? @kimchilover

Comment: The implication "$P(X_n=0)=1$" is false. Note that $X_n=\pm 1/n$ with probability 1/2 works.

Comment: What is your definition of "equally distributed"?

Comment: I think $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}:F_X(t)=F_Y(t)$. @RobertIsrael

Comment: But then it's trivial: $\mathbb E[X_n^4]$ are all the same, so all are equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. As I am not sure what the TA meant, is there some other definition for which it is not trivial? @RobertIsrael

Comment: Perhaps "equally distributed" means that for each $n$ there is some interval $[a_n, b_n]$ on which $X_n$ has uniform distribution.  Then
$\mathbb E[X_n^4] \to 0$ implies $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to 0$, and that implies $X_n \to 0$ a.s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments we have $E[X_n^4]=0$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega |X_n|^4 \,dP = 0
\end{align}
And that means $X_n=0$ a.s.